# Column has dtype object, cannot use method 'nlargest' with this dtype

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using Google Colab and I want to analyze a file from Google Spreadsheet using pandas. I imported them successfully and I can print them out with `pd.DataFrame`

```py
data_tablet = gc.open_by_url(f'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{sheet_id}/edit#gid={tablet_gid}')

tablet_var = data_tablet.worksheet('tablet')
tablet_data = tablet_var.get_all_records()

df_tablet = pd.DataFrame(tablet_data)
print(df_tablet)
```

```
                    name  1st quarter  ...  4th quarter     total
0      Albendazol 400 mg         18.0  ...         60.0        78
1      Alopurinol 100 mg        125.0  ...        821.0       946
2        Ambroksol 30 mg        437.0  ...        798.0  1,235.00
3      Aminofilin 200 mg         70.0  ...        522.0       592
4    Amitriptilin 25 mg          83.0  ...        178.0       261
..                   ...          ...  ...          ...       ...
189   Levoflaksin 250 mg        611.0  ...        822.0  1,433.00
190            Linezolid        675.0  ...        315.0       990
191  Moxifloxacin 400 mg        964.0  ...         99.0  1,063.00
192  Pyrazinamide 500 mg        395.0  ...        189.0       584
193          Vitamin B 6        330.0  ...        825.0  1,155.00

[194 rows x 6 columns]
```

I want to select the top 10 out of 194 items from the `total` and it did not work.

- Selecting the top 10 from `total` and running command below and I get `cannot use method 'nlargest' with this dtype`

```py
# Ambil data 10 terbesar dari 194 item
df_tablet_top10 = df_tablet.nlargest(10, 'total')
print(df_tablet_top10)
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-7-a7295330f7a9> in <module>()
      1 # Ambil data 10 terbesar dari 194 item
----> 2 df_tablet_top10 = df_tablet.nlargest(10, 'total')
      3 print(df_tablet_top10)

2 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/algorithms.py in compute(self, method)
   1273             if not self.is_valid_dtype_n_method(dtype):
   1274                 raise TypeError(
-> 1275                     f"Column {repr(column)} has dtype {dtype}, "
   1276                     f"cannot use method {repr(method)} with this dtype"
   1277                 )

TypeError: Column 'total' has dtype object, cannot use method 'nlargest' with this dtype
```

- But when I select it from `1st quarter` it works just fine

```py
df_tablet_top10 = df_tablet.nlargest(10, '1st quarter')
print(df_tablet_top10)
```

```
                           nama  1st quarter  ...  4th quarter     total
154             Salbutamol 4 mg        981.0  ...         23.0  1,004.00
74   MDT FB dewasa (obat kusta)        978.0  ...        910.0  1,888.00
155   Paracetamol 500 mg Tablet        976.0  ...        503.0  1,479.00
33              Furosemid 40 mg        975.0  ...        524.0  1,499.00
23          Deksametason 0,5 mg        972.0  ...        793.0  1,765.00
21    Bisakodil (dulkolax) 5 mg        970.0  ...        798.0  1,768.00
191         Moxifloxacin 400 mg        964.0  ...         99.0  1,063.00
85          Metronidazol 250 mg        958.0  ...        879.0  1,837.00
96          Nistatin 500.000 IU        951.0  ...        425.0  1,376.00
37             Glimepirid 2 mg         947.0  ...        890.0  1,837.00

[10 rows x 6 columns]
```

Any idea what causes this to happen?

Also, I have changed the format for the `1st quarter` to `total` as `number` on google sheet and it still did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, but not the explanation.

All I did is just to convert the `total` column as `float` with

```
df_tablet['total'] = df_tablet['total'].astype(float)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df_tablet['total'] = df_tablet['total'].astype(float)
df_tablet_top10 = df_tablet.nlargest(10, '1st quarter')
print(df_tablet_top10)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I think that is broken syntax. You probably need this info to fix it: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help  Also, while this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.